# How can I use a node.js worker thread to handle a certain event in IPC (Electron)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, file-manager, node-worker-threads

I am trying to make a native file manager using Electron. I am now at the stage where I want to calculate both folder sizes and file sizes to display them in my renderer process.

For such tasks, I am using Electron's built in IPC solutions, an api wrapper around node:fs in my main process, and a custom class with useful methods and properties.

Calculating file sizes was a straightforward task, and thus seamed calculating folder sizes. Here is my function:

```js
async function calculateFolderSize(_event, path) {
  // find children
  const children = handleReadDir("", path);

  let output = 0;
  for (const child of children) {
    if (child.type === "DT_REG") {
      let size = await calculateFileSize("", child.path);
      output += Number(size ? size.split(",").join("") : "0");
    } else if (child.type === "DT_DIR") {
      let size = await calculateFolderSize("", child.path);
      output += Number(size);
    }
  }
  return output.toString();
}
```

As you can imagine, this function gets really slow, really fast (Imagine the time and resources it will take to calculate the size of a folder located in the root).

To solve this, I tried taking advantage of node's worker_threads module in an attempt to free my main thread from this horrific task:

The main handler:

```js
const { Worker } = require("worker_threads");
const { handleReadDir } = require("../main/apiWrapper");

async function calculateFolderSize(_event, path) {
  const children = handleReadDir("", path);
  let output = 0;

  const calculateChildSizes = async () => {
    const promises = children.map((child) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const worker = new Worker(
          "path/to/workerFile.js",
          {
            workerData: child,
          }
        );

        worker.on("message", (size) => {
          resolve(Number(size));
        });

        worker.on("error", reject);
      });
    });

    const sizes = await Promise.all(promises);
    output += sizes.reduce((acc, size) => acc + size, 0);
  };

  await calculateChildSizes();

  return output.toString();
}

module.exports = { calculateFolderSize };
```

The worker:

```js
const { workerData, parentPort } = require("worker_threads");
const { calculateFileSize } = require("../calculateFileSize");
const { handleReadDir } = require("../../main/apiWrapper");

async function calculateFolderSizeWorker(child) {
  if (child.type === "DT_REG") {
    const size = await calculateFileSize("", child.path);
    parentPort.postMessage(size);
  } else if (child.type === "DT_DIR") {
    let folderSize = 0;
    const entries = handleReadDir("", child.path);

    for (const entry of entries) {
      const childSize = await calculateFolderSizeWorker(entry);
      folderSize += childSize;
    }

    parentPort.postMessage(folderSize);
  }
}

calculateFolderSizeWorker(workerData);
```

It doesn't seem to work and I am running through many different errors like:

Error occurred in handler for 'get-folder-size': TypeError [Error]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

Can you help me? And if not can you suggest another way I can go about this (trying to not use third-party packages as much as possible). Thank you